# Displaying temp reading on an Arduino with more than 1 decimal digit

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a code sample which helps me to display temperature:

```cpp
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <OLED_I2C.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
OLED myOLED(8, 9, 8); // 8pin - SDA , 9pin - SCL

extern uint8_t RusFont[];
extern uint8_t MegaNumbers[];
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];

void setup() {
  sensors.begin();
  myOLED.begin();
}

void loop() {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  myOLED.clrScr();
  myOLED.setFont(RusFont);
  myOLED.print("Ntvgthfnehf", CENTER, 0);
  myOLED.setFont(SmallFont);
  myOLED.print("iarduino.ru", CENTER, 55);
  myOLED.setFont(MegaNumbers);
  myOLED.print(String(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0), 1), CENTER, 9); // Displaying temp
  myOLED.update();
  delay(100);
}
```

How to make the display show more than 1 decimal digit? Or is it limited by the device?

Comment: not sure if I understand the problem. Docs tell me that `(String(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0) , 1)` creates a string with 1 decimal place. Are you looking for `(String(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0) , 2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the , 1 to a , 2.
This will tell the Arduino that you want to print it with a two decimal place.
eg:

> myOLED.print(String(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0), 2), CENTER, 9);